# Transpose Vec<Vec<T>> to Vec<Vec<T>> where T has no Copy trait

Tags: rust

The goal is to achieve the following conversion from A to B both of type Vec<Vec<T>> in Rust, where type T has no Copy trait:

A = [ [t1,t2,t3], [t4,t5,t6] ]

B = [ [t1,t4], [t2,t5], [t3,t6] ]

Through testing, I know the next three ideas **do work very well**:

Suppose A is a vector of M elements, each of which is a vector of N elements.

Idea One:

```
let B: Vec<Vec<T>> = (0..N)
        .map(|i| A
            .iter()
            .map(|x| (*x.iter().skip(i).next().unwrap()).clone())
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        )
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Idea Two:

```
let B: Vec<Vec<T>> = (0..N)
        .map(|i| A
            .iter()
            .map(|x| x[i].clone())
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        )
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Idea Three:

```
let A = A.into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<T>>();
let B: Vec<Vec<T>> = (0..N)
        .map(|i| A
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .filter(|(v, _)| *v % N == i)
            .map(|(_, j)| j.clone())
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        )
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Is there any other idea that **avoids using the Clone trait or indexing (such as A[i])**, or at least tries to use them **as little as possible**? Thanks in advance.

I tried to find my answer on Google, stackoverflow, github or Rust Programming community. Unfortunately, I can't see any similar questions.

I expect there might be some clues to solve this question in a way that **avoids using the Clone trait or indexing (such as A[i])**, or at least tries to use them **as little as possible**.

I believe this is rather simple for an experienced Rust programmer, but I am kinda stuck somewhere that I have no idea about.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid indexing? I can understand that `Clone` may not be implemented by `T`, but I don't understand why indexing should be avoided.

Comment: The linked Q&A contains two code samples that meet the no-clone no-index criteria.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I remember instead of iterator, each indexing requires an implicit boundary check by Rust that will bring a little time cost, no?

Comment: Yes, it is a little time cost. Are you willing to pay a big time cost to avoid it?

Comment: @DietrichEpp May I ask why there will be a big time cost to avoid indexing? I am still a rookie in Rust.

Comment: If you look at the top accepted answer, you'll see that it creates a new vector called `row_iters`. This seems like a high price to pay just to avoid some indexing.

Comment: @DietrichEpp This does make much sense. Concerning avoiding creating scratch vectors, the second answer of the same/similar question (How to transpose a vector of vectors in Rust? The link is on the very top) written by kmdreko should be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using no cloning or indexing: convert the rows into consuming iterators, then to make each row in the output, take one item from each of those iterators.

```rs
let matrix = vec![vec![1, 2, 3], vec![4, 5, 6]];

let num_cols = matrix.first().unwrap().len();
let mut row_iters: Vec<_> = matrix.into_iter().map(Vec::into_iter).collect();
let mut out: Vec<Vec<_>> = (0..num_cols).map(|_| Vec::new()).collect();

for out_row in out.iter_mut() {
    for it in row_iters.iter_mut() {
        out_row.push(it.next().unwrap());
    }
}

println!("{:?}", out);
// [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b3a47204c2a29d951c2a87c2e0d8098)

If you don't like the `for` loops either, you can replace them with this:

```rs
let out: Vec<Vec<_>> = (0..num_cols)
    .map(|_| row_iters.iter_mut().map(|it| it.next().unwrap()).collect())
    .collect();
```

Comment: This works nicely! May I further ask if it works without using Clone()/indexing or causing any error of Copy trait because you use into_iter() to transfer the ownership and use iter_mut() to allow the Move trait, since it does look similar to my Idea One to some extent? Thank you very much.

Comment: @GoGoCommando Yes, `into_iter` makes an owning iterator. The `iter_mut` is used to repeatedly iterate over the vectors in `out` and the iterators in `row_iters`; the former need to be mutable because you're pushing to them, the latter because you're taking from them and advancing the iterators.